# javascript: setting a.onclick doesn't work at first run

Tags: javascript, events

I use code like this to dynamically create some link-based controls:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function BuildControls (id, ...)
    {  
        var div = document.getElementById (id);  
        /* some stuff with var sp=document.createElement('span'); */
        var a = document.createElement ('a');
        a.innerHTML = on ? 'Cancel' : captions_do[i];
        a.className = class_do;
        a.style.display = on2 ? '' : 'none';
        a.id = 'iAccept'+id+'_'+i+'Control';
        div.appendChild (sp);
        div.innerHTML+='<br />';
        div.appendChild (a);
        a.onclick = function () {alert ('wtf')};
        div.innerHTML+='<br />';
    }
</script>
...
<div id="someid"></div>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    BuildControls ('someid', ...);
</script>
```

So when I click on the link, it does nothing. If I call a.onclick() explicitly, it works. What is wrong?

Comment: Don't know if it is a typo, but in the code above it says "onclick" not "a.onclick".... So you are creating global (window) onclick. Probably not what you had in mind.

Comment: Sorry, that was a misprint. I had it right in my code, certainly. In fact, the real problem appeared to be in the next line.

Comment: I would suggest using JQuery for better cross-browser compatibility, as well as DOM manipulation, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> div.innerHTML+='<br />';

That is syntactical sugar for:

> div.innerHTML= div.innerHTML+'<br />';

Which makes it clearer what is happening: you just serialised the entire contents of the div to HTML, added a tiny string, and parsed the results back into HTML. Even if it worked flawlessly, that'd be really inefficient.

When you serialise an element, you lose any non-attribute-based information attached to it, including JavaScript properties, event handlers and listeners. Say goodbye to your onclick.

*Never use “innerHTML+=”. It is always a mistake.*

An alternative is to set innerHTML on a standalone div not attached to the document, then append its childNodes one-by-one to the element where you really want it.

But for something this simple, you should just be using the standard DOM methods:

```
div.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
```

Comment: I've already found this out, thank you. Seems that you answer is the most perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as posted works fine in IE7 and Firefox - there must be something in the `/* ... */` that's breaking it.

Comment: I've updated the code, removing some ...s. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: hm... I tried to remove the <br> adding thing. It helps. Thank you.

Comment: @stanch: mixing `innerHTML` and direct DOM manipulation is generally a bad idea - only do it if you know what you're doing ;)